# How to fold a distance?

Tags: matlab

with this code I try to say that if the distance between points of c and the vertical line of c is less than 10 (for example) all pixel that contains this distance equal to 1. but this code give me 1 for all along the vertical line. How can I improve the code?

```
clear all
close all

c=zeros(500,500);
c(:,250)=1;
dim=size(c);

D = bwdist(cumsum(c, 2,'reverse')> 0, 'euclidean'); %Sorry I forgot 'reverse'

c(200,400)=1;
c(400,255)=1
c(250,252)=1
c(300,258)=1
c(100,270)=1
c(130,256)=1
c(310,260)=1
figure, imagesc (c)

for i=1:dim(1)
    for j= 1: dim(2)
        if D(i,j)>0 & D(i,j)<10
            c(i,j)=1;
        end
    end
end

figure, imagesc(c)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your euclidian distance function wasnt quite doing what you wanted. I changed one line in your code to do what I think you want to do. I detect pixels and draw a perpendicular from those pixels to the vertical line

```
clear all
close all

c=zeros(500,500);
c(:,250)=1;
dim=size(c);

D = bwdist(cumsum(c, 2,'reverse')> 0, 'euclidean'); %Sorry I forgot 'reverse'

c(200,400)=1;
c(400,255)=1;
c(250,252)=1;
c(300,258)=1;
c(100,270)=1;
c(130,256)=1;
c(310,260)=1;
figure(1);
imagesc (c);

for i=1:dim(1)
    for j= 1: dim(2)
        if c(i,j)==1 && j~=250
            c(i,[250:260])=1;
        end
    end
end

figure(2);
imagesc(c);
```

Comment: I just changed the code a bit to include the distance of 10 you wanted

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Initially `c` is all zeros, apart from the line of ones at 250. The `cumsum` changes the line of ones into `1..500` but `> 0` changes it back into just ones... :-S

You update `c` *after* calculating `D`. Is that your problem?

Aside, the loops are slow, complex and not necessary. Try something like this instead:

```
c(D > 0 & D < 10) = 1;
```

Comment: for example if we take the point c(250,252) : I want to say that points between c (250,250) and c (250,252) wil equal to 1 and not 0 (in the end, it is equivalent to a line of 1 between this points)? Is it more understanding?